# How to access image view from recycler-view item using ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()

Tags: android

```
 RecyclerView.ViewHolder imageViewDrawerIcon;
    public void  childOFrecyclerView(){
        int childCount = myRecyclerView.getChildCount();
        Log.d("Countttt","Count"+childCount);
        myRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                for(int i=0;i<=childCount;i++)
                 imageViewDrawerIcon = myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                if(imageViewDrawerIcon.itemView instanceof MyView){
                    imageViewDrawerIcon.itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_imageview).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }  
            }
        });
    }
```

I have 10 items view in Recycler view. I have to access imageview whose id is
`my_imageview` but I am getting:

> android.view.View
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null
>   object reference

Please suggest how to get ItemView image view from Recycler view in Android.

Comment: please post your full adapter class

Comment: its hard to post because it very complicated can you please tell me how to count visible item view count of recycler-view ? @ZaidMirza

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding regarding how RecyclerView works. It does NOT hold all the items its adapter can access, justvslightly more than can fit on screen. getChildCount returns the number of allocated child views, not total number of entries. FindViewHolderForAdapterPosition fetches the ViewHolder, that is used for Database entry under said index, may be and often is null.